# Find the difference between the maximum and the minimum number of apples that a person gets.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> 120 apples are to be distributed among 7 people such that each person has atleast 13 apples. Find the difference between the maximum and the minimum number of apples that a person gets.

I don't know its answer. It appeared in 1 test. I remember the question so I was solving it today

Minimum number of apple= 13
Maximum numbers
Each person can get atleast 13
so, a=a'+13
b=b'+13
c=c'+13
d=d'+13
e=e'+13
f=f'+13
g=g'+13
adding all the above seven equation
a'+b'+c'+d'+e'+f'+g'+91=120
a'+b'+c'+d'+e'+f'+g'=29
So applying partition,one case can be that only one person gets 29 apples
suppose a is that person
so,a=29+13=42
So the difference will be 29

Am I right? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: As I understand the problem, I agree with you answer.  Start by distributing the minimum $13$ to each person, and we have $29$ apples left.  So the difference between the maximum number and minimum number a person can get could be as much as $29$.  I'm a little doubtful that was the intended interpretation because it doesn't actually require much knowledge of partitions.

Comment: Are you looking for the *maximum* difference btw the max and min no. of apples that a person gets?

Comment: just the difference between the minimum and the maximum number @MathLover

Comment: just the difference between the minimum and the maximum number @MathLover

Comment: The difference between the maximum and the minimum number of apples a person can get lies between $1$ and $29$. If the questions asks for the maximum difference then the answer is $29$, and if the question is about the minimum difference then the answer is $1$.